# Youtube doesn't change browser's history on android devices

Tags: android, browser, youtube, browser-history, bookmarks

I am making an app that needs to know what URL is the user visiting in the default browser.
To do this i get the last visited URL in the browser's history, but for youtube there is a problem, that is when you are already on youtube and open a video the new URL is not stored in the browser's history, only the title. Now i tired it with an older android device (2.3.6) and  neither the new title is stored the last visited URL remains m.youtube.com

Do you have any suggestion to solve my problem?

Comment: Your app is already doomed.  Not all users use the default browser, and not all phones even ship with the Google default browser (no Samsung device does).  If you need this, your app isn't going to work for many users.  For that matter, knowing that you can get this information makes me want to download firefox to prevent apps from using it.  That's creepy.

Comment: I can make the app working also in other browsers like chrome but i encountered this problem with the default browser. The URL is not used for a bad purpose and the user obviously will know what my app does.